# Why can't my program output the results I want?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int op1;
    char op;
    float op2;
    scanf("%d%2c%f", &op1, &op, &op2);
    printf("%d%2c%f", op1, op, op2); 
    return 0;
};
```

Why, when I input `1 * 2`, do I get `32 *2.000000` instead of `1* 2`?

Comment: Why do you use the format `%2c` to read *one* character?

Comment: `scanf("%d%2c%f", &op1, &op, &op2);` — `scanf("%d %c%f", &op1, &op, &op2);` see the added space too?

Comment: The `.000000` appears because `%f` requests a fixed point output with six decimal places.  Using %g` would probably print the floating-point value with no decimal point or fractional digits.

Comment: `scanf("%2c", &op)` means that you read two bytes, and store them at address `&op`. But there is only one byte allocated there. So it overwrites on something else. Luckily enough (it could have gone way worse than that), that happens to be the lowest byte of `op1`. So `op1` least significative byte (so `op1%256`) is overwritten with whatever char you type as 2nd char after the first number. In your case, that happens to be a space. Ascii code 32. Hence 32.

Comment: If you had typed `1*A2` instead of `1* 2` you would get `65*2.0` as result. Because ASCII code of `A` is 65, and that 65 overwrites 8 least significant bits of `op1` (on your machine, with your compiler. It would be different on a machine that stores least significant bytes first. And could be different with another compiler that makes other choice for order of variables in memory. Not even mentionning alignment influence).

Comment: If you had typed `1000*A2`, then op1 is first `1000`, so bytes `0, 0, 3, 232` from most to least significant bytes (because 1000 is 256×3 + 232) (stored in order 232, 3, 0, 0 on your machine, since this is obviously a little endian machine). Then, the two bytes read, (char `*` and char `A`) are stored into `op` for `*` and into the least significant byte of `op1` is overwritten with ascii code of `A`, that is 65. Turning op1 into `0×2²⁴+0×2¹⁶+3×2⁸+65×2⁰` = `3×256+65` = 833. And result would have been `833*2.000`. Just try it :D

Comment: Shorter (and more accurate, because everything I've said is just what happened in your case, but no rule says that it should happen that way. It could also have overwritten `op2`. Or an empty useless padding byte. Or a forbidden memory area, resulting in many different outcomes), version is: "you wrote two bytes into a 1 byte variable, so anything can happen".

Comment: @chrslg: good insight!  where are you from?

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is you read 2 characters with `%2c` into an object `op` that only has space for one.  This has undefined behavior.

As commented by *chrslg*, writing beyond the single byte of memory occupied by `op` probably corrupts the value of `op1`, which becomes `32`, the ASCII value  for the space character, but this is only a tentative explanation and something else might be happening, and indeed the behavior will likely be different on a different computer or with different compilation options.

To ignore the whitespace before the operator, add a space in the format string: use
`"%d %c%f"`.

Regarding the `2.000000` output, the default number of decimal places for `%f` is 6. Use `%g` to omit non significant decimals.

Also note that you should check the return value of `scanf()` and remove the `;` after the body of the `main` function.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int op1;
    char op;
    float op2;

    if (scanf("%d %c%f", &op1, &op, &op2) == 3) {
        printf("%d %c %g\n", op1, op, op2); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [answer from chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77164343/15261315) has identified the issue in your code. However, you may want to be a little bit more sophisticated to handle situations that `scanf` may not handle very well. An example follows, using `strtol` and `strtof` to find integer and floating point values. It checks the return values from those functions to determine if a value has been read successfully. If an error occurs it emits a meaningful error code (encoded in an enum).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef enum {
    SUCCESS = 0,
    NOTHING_READ,
    OP1_NOT_READ,
    OP_NOT_READ,
    OP2_NOT_READ
} ParseStatus;
)
bool is_valid_op(char op) {
    switch (op) {
        case '*': case '-':
        case '+': case '/':
        return true;
   
        default:
        return false;
    };
}

ParseStatus parse_expr(char *expr, int *op1, char *op, float *op2) {
    while (isspace(*expr)) expr++;
    if (!*expr) return NOTHING_READ;

    char *end;
    *op1 = strtol(expr, &end, 10);
    if (expr == end) {
        return OP1_NOT_READ;
    }

    expr = end;
 
    while (isspace(*expr)) expr++;
    if (!*expr) return OP_NOT_READ;

    *op = *expr++;
    if (!is_valid_op(*op)) {
        return OP_NOT_READ;
    }
    
    while (isspace(*expr)) expr++;
    if (!*expr) return OP2_NOT_READ;

    *op2 = strtof(expr, &end);
    if (expr == end) {
        return OP2_NOT_READ;
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}

int main(void) {
    char op;
    int op1;
    float op2;
    ParseStatus ps = parse_expr("6*4.5", &op1, &op, &op2);

    if (ps != SUCCESS) {
        printf("Improperly formatted expression.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%d %c %0.2f\n", op1, op, op2);

    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
6 * 4.50
```